# How to navigate through ionic app depending on data recieved from arduino via bluetooth

Tags: ionic-framework, bluetooth, arduino, ionic3, hc-05

I am trying to communicate between arduino blutooth HC-05 and ionic app.
I have succesfully connected the app to blutooth device and I am able to to read the data from the arduino and everything is fine.However, when I send data from arduino to the application it stores the data in a buffer and wait for someone to click a button in the app and read the data.

How can I read the data from the buffer contiuosly without the need to click any button in ionic and depeding on that value it keep navigating through the app?
Here is the code of the select device page where the user choose which device to control. Example: when arduino send '1' to ionic, it should enter the light page, and if it recieve '2',it should enter Ac box and so on.

This code works,but I must click the button to read data from buffer and then navigate to different pages.
How can I keep checking if data in buffer continuously untill I read either 1,2,3,or 4 without the need to click any button.

Answer (score 0):

Attached are the codes 
[HTML FILE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAt88.png)

[TypeScript file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7zrE.png)